# Having trouble uncompressing a few files

Tags: command-line, zip, compression

So I have to uncompress 4 different files. When I do

```
file file1
file file2
file file3
 file file4
```

for example, different messages are displayed. For example one starts like `"gzip compressed data, …`, another starts like `RAR archive data, v1d, os: Unix…`, another starts like `compress'd data 16 bits…`

I am not really sure how to differentiate between the different uncompressing commands. Which one would I use for each?

For those who asked, the filenames are actually `file1`, `file2`, etc. They have no visible extensions at all.

Comment: Can you show the actual names of these files?

Comment: And the actual output of the `file` commands?

Answer (score 45):

You can use the command `file` to determine the type of compression that was used for a particular file.

#### Examples

```
$ file file.zip 
file.zip: Zip archive data, at least v1.0 to extract
```

To uncompress this file, use `unzip`.

```
$ file file.rar 
file.rar: RAR archive data, v1d, os: Win32
```

To uncompress this file, use `unrar`.

```
$ file file.7z 
file.7z: 7-zip archive data, version 0.3
```

To uncompress this file, user `7z`.

```
$ file file.tgz 
file.tgz: gzip compressed data, from Unix, last modified: Sun Oct 13 01:14:43 2013
```

To uncompress this file, use `tar`. Use the switches `tar zxvf`.

```
$ file file.tar.bz2 
file.tar.bz2: bzip2 compressed data, block size = 900k
```

To uncompress this file, use `tar`. Use the switches `tar jxvf`.

```
$ file afile.gz 
afile.gz: gzip compressed data, was "afile", from Unix, last modified: Sun Oct 13 01:10:19 2013
```

To uncompress this file, use `gunzip`.

#### Extensions

`gunzip` is one of the tools that does care what the files are named. The files need to have one of the following extensions so that `gunzip` can uncompress them.

- `.gz`, `-gz`, `.z`, `-z`, or `_z` (ignoring case)

If you have a file that was compressed using `gzip` and attempt to unzip it you'll encounter this message:

```
$ file afile_not_named_gz 
afile_not_named_gz: gzip compressed data, was "afile", from Unix, last modified: Sun Oct 13 01:10:19 2013

$ gunzip afile_not_named_gz
gzip: afile_not_named_gz: unknown suffix -- ignored
```

The easiest way to fix this is to rename the file so that it has an extension:

```
$ mv afile_not_named_gz afile_not_named_gz.gz
$ gunzip afile_not_named_gz.gz

$ ls |grep afile_not_named_gz
afile_not_named_gz
```

You can also pacify `gunzip` by using the `-S` switch, and tell it the suffix (extension) if it's something other than the ones listed above.

```
$ gunzip -S _gz afile_not_named_gz
$
```

Realize that whatever you use as an extension gets stripped off by `gunzip` though:

```
$ ls -l | grep afile_not_named 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml       0 Oct 13 08:04 afile_not_named
```

Comment: I am still a bit confused for a few of them. I have 2 files left that I need to uncompress. First off I will say that neither file has an extension, but when I "file file1" and "file file2" without the quotation marks it still shows the same messages that you have listed.

Comment: Neither file actually has a . extension if that makes a difference. One of the messages is "file1: compress'd data 16 bits" so for this one I have tried using "uncompress file1" but it did not work. The last one I am confused with displays the message "file2: gzip compressed data, was "file2", from Unix, last modified:..." so I tried to use something like "gunzip file2" but that did not work. The message that appeared was "gzip: file2: unknown suffix -- ignored

Comment: @John - extensions are typically meaningless in Linux/Unix. Files contain a header (magic number) that identifies what the files actually are. `gunzip` if one of the tools that does care, I'd rename the files to file1.gz and try `gunzip file1.gz`.

Comment: @John - I've updated the answer to include some additional info on gunzip.

Comment: @slm can u please tell me the difference between the cases when we use tar -zxvf and when we use gzip command to decompress

Comment: @RohanBhatia, you *can* use `gunzip` on `tar.gz` and `tgz` files. Those are tar files that have been compressed with gzip. Tar is just a way to combine multiple files, since gzip only works on a single file. But if you decompress it with gzip, you'll get a tar file that still has to be unpacked. Your only option is to either use file extensions as a hint or to decompress it and then check again if it might be a tar file.

Comment: Also, I really just came here to point out that most people make `tar` look so scary. There's even an xkcd about it. But modern `tar` detects compression type, so you just need `tar -xf my_file.tar.gz` (etc). `x` is to extract and `f` says we're specifying a file. Similarly, to make tar files is just `tar -cf output.tar.gz input1 input2 [..]` (`c` for create).

Answer (score 0):

In *nix, there are a lot of different compression formats, and many different commands to uncompress them.

```
tar -xvf filename
```

Usually works in most cases. For other formats, use `unzip`, `unrar`, etc ...

See also: `man tar`

Comment: `tar -xvf filename` will only work for tar-archives. (newer versons will autodetect compressed tar-archives and use the appropriate uncompressor), but it won't work with other compressed files (e.g. `file.gz`) or `zip` archives...

Comment: @umläute I have tried it on my own system and it seems to work for gzip archives.

Comment: i said `zip` archives (as produced by winzip and the like); i'd say that there are *archives* that are not necessarily produced by (or compatible to ) `ar`